# How to see octopus deployment stages in Azure boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy, azure-boards

I am using AzureDevOps for build and release pipeline until Internal Test Stage and all production stages are deployed using Octopus. First stage in Azure is configured to create a release in Octopus and is successfully showing the deployment to Internal Test in work item. see image below

[image]

Now, I want all the deployments that we promote in octopus to later production stages to be displayed here as well or a link to octopus url that takes you to the related stages.

Please guide is this possible?

Comment: Hi Octopus deploy urls can only be added as hylinks to azure devops work items, as Deployment field doesnot support octopus deploy url. Please check out below answer.

Comment: Hi @sam Did you get a chance to try out below solution? how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Octopus deploy urls cannot be displayed on the Deployment, Development, and Related Work fields in azure devops work item. For these fields only support links to work items, azure builds, PRs,etc from azure devops.

I donot know much about Octopus, but if there is a tool or octopus api that can get the azure devops workitem id from the build information that associated to the packages contained in the release, then you can use [azure devops rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to add a hyperlink to octopus url in azure devops work items. The you can find the hyperlinks in the links tab as below sceenshot.

[image]

The first step is to integrate your azure devops with Octopus. Please check the steps [here](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers/tfs-azure-devops/using-octopus-extension).

And then Configure your azure devops pipeline to push build information which includes work items to Octopus. Please check the octopus document [Azure DevOps work item tracking integration](https://octopus.com/docs/managing-releases/issue-tracking/azure-devops#availability).

Then, add a [script step](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts/run-a-script-step)s to run below scripts in Octopus to update the azure work items with the hyperlink to octopus url. (You need to get the id of work items in octopus before run below scripts)

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/{azure devops organization}/{azure devops organization project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitem id}?api-version=5.1"

$body='[{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "Hyperlink",
      "url": "octopus url"
    }
  }]'

$wicrpat ="Personal access token from azure devops"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($wicrpat)"))

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method patch -Body $body
```

Please check [the steps here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access) to get Personal access token.

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for more information about work item update api.

You can also [add a widget to Dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/add-widget-to-dashboard?view=azure-devops) to display Octopus deploys in your azure devops project.(Go the **Dashboards** under **Overview**, click **edit** and search and add octopus deploy widget)

Hope above helps!